# AttributeError: module 'regex' has no attribute 'Pattern'

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, google-colaboratory

I'm getting this error while trying to run this code in google colab:

```
!pip install dataprep
from dataprep.eda import create_report
```

Error:

```
NumExpr defaulting to 2 threads.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-db62224f8a79> in <module>()
----> 1 from dataprep.eda import create_report

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/casual.py in TweetTokenizer()
    355 
    356     @property
--> 357     def WORD_RE(self) -> regex.Pattern:
    358         """Core TweetTokenizer regex"""
    359         # Compiles the regex for this and all future instantiations of TweetTokenizer.

AttributeError: module 'regex' has no attribute 'Pattern'
```

Thing is pretty strange, as this code worked fine yesterday.
Any ideas?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0EU9.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a [known issue in NLTK](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/6428c9288a86658cb3d9a1e91816c4bcf162a6f0). Perhaps update the NLTK version.

Comment: Thank you!
My nltk version is 3.6.4 , it was released 11 hours ago (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/releases/tag/3.6.4) that's why my code worked fine yesterday. But the strangest thing is the new release has this issue (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/casual.py).

Now I'll downgrade my nltk version till they'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by upgrading to the latest versio to nltk 3.7, by using below command.

```
pip install nltk -U
```